# Connection was reset when submitting a multipart form in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

I have been trying to submit a very simple form with an attachment using Zend Framework but it isn't working. All I got is "The connection was reset" error message. This is the code I am using (simplified to make it easier to test, debug and understand):

The View (upload.phtml)

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/manage/images/uploadfiles" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

The Controller (ImagesController.php):

```
public function uploadfilesAction() { /* */ }
```

The controller is empty (I had something else but it doesn't make a difference. This is the error I get:

> The connection was reset
>   The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

These are some of the parameters on my php.ini file:

```
file_uploads=On
max_file_uploads=20
upload_max_filesize=8M
memory_limit=128M
max_input_time=60
```

I've been playing with those values but nothing happens.

Any clue about what could be happening?

Comment: whats in your server error log

Comment: [Fri Jul 05 08:25:27 2013] [notice] child pid 10058 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as always the error was fixed with a full server restart. Before doing that, I tried restarting each individual component, changing parameters, etc. Nothing worked until I restarted the whole server.

I am also running memcached (don't think it has something to do with the problem though).

I have some suspicions that the problem could be related with the user/group running my apache server.

Let me know if someone encounter this same issue, I've been struggling with this problem and tried everything, so I may be able to help you.

Thanks @DevZer0 for your question, I hadn't have a look in the apache error log before you asked.